# Get exitcode from a background process in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, background-process

I have a Bash script that execute a command in background, to can show a progress-bar during the command execution, this is the code:

```
# Background command
dpkg -i $DPKG_COMMAND >/dev/null &

# Progress-Bar
while ps | grep $! &>/dev/null; do
  echo -n "."
  sleep 0.5
done

EXIT_CODE=???????
```

...but I need to know the exit code of the background process to can determine how to continue the execution of my script.

Comment: You can use `wait` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570356/4325768).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait on the child which will hang your process until the child completes, you can use the "trap" command for signal SIGCHLD. This way your parent process can continue doing things until the child terminates at which time the "trap" statements are executed. Then based on the result, you would take whatever action you need.

Comment: Can you take a little example, please?